# Customizing a CompositeC1 global datatype form

Tags: c1-cms

I am building a console application and am currently using the standard form markup that is produced when you create your global datatype.  I know you can edit this form markup to change what is displayed, but is there a way to change the layout so you can have more than 1 column for a large datatype or have the ability to design the form as you would like.  For example, right now you get one field per table row.  What if you would like to have 2 fields per table row, or insert a paragraph between two table rows?

I was wanting to stick with using the standard datatype forms to take advantage of the stock workflows, buttons, etc.  If that isn't a possibility, how else would you proceed, a custom form?

Answer (score 0):

it's not exact solution you are looking for, but have a look into tabs: http://c1packages.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Composite.Community.Blog/Composite.Community.Blog.Package/Package/App_Data/Composite/DynamicTypeForms/Composite/Community/Blog/Entries.xml

```
        <TabPanels>
        <FieldGroup Label="Settings">
            <TextBox Label="Title" Help="The title of the blog entry. Consider a short title for quick reference in lists and feeds.">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <cms:bind source="Title" />
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </FieldGroup>
        <FieldGroup Label="Tags">
            .....
        </FieldGroup>
        <XhtmlEditor Label="Content" Help="The content of the blog entry." ClassConfigurationName="common">
            <XhtmlEditor.Xhtml>
                <cms:bind source="Content" />
            </XhtmlEditor.Xhtml>
        </XhtmlEditor>
    </TabPanels>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response aeont.  I think that is the route I'll go for the time being.